# im trying to create the users input into a list set in a transaction log: cannot convert string to int: for 'items.Add(n.name, n);'

Tags: c#

```
class TransactionManager
    {
        private Dictionary<int, Item> items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
        private Dictionary<int, Transaction> Transactions = new Dictionary<int, Transaction>();

        public void NewTransactionEntry(Item c, Item n, Item p, Item q, Item d)
        {
            items.Add(c.code, c);
            items.Add(n.name, n);
            items.Add(c.price, c);
            items.Add(c.quantity, c);
            items.Add(c.date, c);
        }

        public Dictionary<int, Transaction> FindTransaction()
        {
            return Transactions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying to set the users input into transaction log

Comment: using these variables, the itemname and date are both set as strings but how to i impliment them the same way as the integers

Comment: You can [edit] your post - no need to put it in the comments.

Comment: why do you need to put your items into `Dictionary<int, Item> items`

Comment: i did it as an accident, as i was refrencing another example code. what can i replace the dictionary<int, item> with

Comment: Why is `items` a `Dictionary` vs say a `List`?